# mousePressed creates 3D cube in Processing

Tags: 3d, rotation, processing

I'm somewhat new to Processing, and I'm trying to make a mousePressed event which creates rotating cubes on the screen. Next phase would be to create collision events between them, but for now I'm with another problem: it works, but only if the mouse is pressed, while I want them to last even if the mouse is NOT pressed.

Here's the code, I tried a workaround,cycling with an infinite for, and it created a weird glitch of all these rotating cubes just spinning until going into 0,0... 
Actually void draw is empty 'cause everything just keeps getting erased.

```
int pointmousex;
int pointmousey;
float a=0;
float r=0;
float co=100;
float Cubox[]= {
};
float Cuboy[]= {
};
float Cuboz[]= {
};
boolean bgON=true;

void setup() {
  size(800, 640, P3D);
  colorMode(HSB);
  background(0);
  smooth();
}

void draw_box(float x, float y, float box_size, float rot) {
  float z=box_size;
  translate(x, y, z);
  rotateX(rot);
  rotateY(rot);
  fill(map(co, 0, 255, 100, 255));
  box(box_size, box_size, box_size);
}

void draw() {
  if (bgON==true) {
    fill(255, 230, 200);
    rect(0, 0, width, height);
  }

  r=r+0.1;
}

void mousePressed() {
  int pointmousex = mouseX;
  int pointmousey = mouseY;
  lights();
  draw_box(pointmousex, pointmousey, 100, r*0.2);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key=='b' || key=='B') {
    if (bgON==true) {
      bgON = false;
    } else {
      bgON = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do more complicated stuff with boxes I advice you to create class:

```java
class Box{
  float x,y,z, box_size, rot;

  //create instance of box with specific position and starting rotation
  Box(float x, float y, float box_size, float rot){
    this.z = box_size;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.box_size = box_size;
    this.rot = rot;
  }

  void draw_box(){
    pushMatrix();
    translate(x, y, z);
    //adding R will rotate all boxes
    rotateX(r + rot);
    rotateY(r + rot);
    fill(map(co, 0, 255, 100, 255));
    box(box_size);
    popMatrix();
  }

  //here you can add more complex methods like colision ...
}
```

Then you have have to create global array for storing these boxes

```java
final static ArrayList<Box> boxes = new ArrayList();
```

Inside mouse event just create new box and add it into `boxes`

```java
void mousePressed() {
  boxes.add( new Box(mouseX, mouseY, 100, r*0.5));
}
```

Last thing you need to do is redraw scene (every box) every time `draw()` is called:

```java
void draw() {
  background(255,230,200);
  for(Box box: boxes){
    box.draw_box();
  }
  r=r+0.01;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Majlik :) while trying to grasp why you used an arraylist, i've found out you can also change an arraylist to an array and tried to do a collision system with for cycles and registering the x-y-z location,but didn't succeed in it unluckily... i've just reached a collision system on the border of the screen, not between cubes, sadly...

Thanks for this advice, anyway, it was so nice!